# Hi! the problem with returning to the previous menu of the telegram bot on python

Tags: python, telebot

Hello everyone I am writing a bot for cash accounting. Faced with such a problem that after using one of the buttons "Отчет" "Инкас" "Нал" "Назад" the rest stop working. After repeating the command /start, you can use any of these functions again. This is probably due to the fact that the bot does not forget the previous steps, or does not return to the previous menu. But at the same time, no errors appear when executing the script

Here is my code. added bat.clear_step_handler but it didn't help

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6270390806:AAHPDkzSwGofxLMDkFGSI7kRXRmcictP23I')

start_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
start_menu.row('Пальмы', 'Горки')

palma_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
palma_menu.row('Отчет', 'Инкас', 'Нал', 'Назад')

palma_ot_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)

gorki_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
gorki_menu.row('Отчет', 'Инкас', 'Нал', 'Назад')

gorki_ot_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)




@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def start(m):
    user_id = m.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=f'Выбери заправку', reply_markup=start_menu)



@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def send_text(m):
    if m.text == 'Пальмы':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Выбери действие', reply_markup=palma_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, handle_palma_menu)
    elif m.text == 'Горки':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Выбери действие', reply_markup=gorki_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, handle_gorki_menu)


def handle_palma_menu(m):
    if m.text == 'Отчет':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму выручки', reply_markup=palma_ot_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_revenue_palmi)
    elif m.text == 'Инкас':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму инкаса')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_collection_palmi)
    elif m.text == 'Нал':
        cash_report_palmi(m)
    elif m.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Выбери заправку', reply_markup=start_menu)

def handle_gorki_menu(m):
    if m.text == 'Отчет':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму выручки', reply_markup=gorki_ot_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_revenue_gorki)
    elif m.text == 'Инкас':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму инкаса')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_collection_gorki)
    elif m.text == 'Нал':
        cash_report_gorki(m)
    elif m.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Выбери заправку', reply_markup=start_menu)


def get_revenue_palmi(m):
    revenue = m.text
    bot.clear_step_handler(m)
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму зарплаты')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_salary_palmi, revenue)

def get_salary_palmi(m, revenue):
    salary = m.text

    try:
        revenue = int(revenue)
        salary = int(salary)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введены некорректные данные. Попробуйте снова')
        return

    current_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    current_date_str = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    result = revenue - salary

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS palmi_report (
                  date TEXT,
                  revenue INTEGER,
                  salary INTEGER,
                  result INTEGER,
                  collection INTEGER
               )""")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO palmi_report(date, revenue, salary, result) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (current_date, revenue, salary, result))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f'Отчет за {current_date_str} готов:\nВыручка: {revenue} руб.\nЗарплата: {salary} руб.\nОстаток: {result} руб.', reply_markup=palma_menu)

def get_collection_palmi(m):
    collection = m.text

    try:
        collection = int(collection)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введены некорректные данные. Попробуйте снова')
        return

    current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM palmi_report WHERE date = ?", (current_date,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO palmi_report(date, revenue, salary, result, collection) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (current_date, 0, 0, 0, collection))
    else:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE palmi_report SET collection = ? WHERE date = ?", (collection, current_date))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f'Инкас {current_date}:\nСумма инкаса: {collection} руб.', reply_markup=palma_menu)

def cash_report_palmi(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(result) - SUM(collection) FROM palmi_report")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()

    if row is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нет данных для отчета")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Остаток нала: {row[0]} руб.", reply_markup=palma_menu)




def get_revenue_gorki(m):
    revenue = m.text
    bot.clear_step_handler(m)
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введи сумму зарплаты')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(m, get_salary_gorki, revenue)

def get_salary_gorki(m, revenue):
    salary = m.text

    try:
        revenue = int(revenue)
        salary = int(salary)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введены некорректные данные. Попробуйте снова')
        return

    current_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    current_date_str = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    result = revenue - salary

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gorki_report (
                  date TEXT,
                  revenue INTEGER,
                  salary INTEGER,
                  result INTEGER,
                  collection INTEGER
               )""")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gorki_report(date, revenue, salary, result) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (current_date, revenue, salary, result))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f'Отчет за {current_date_str} готов:\nВыручка: {revenue} руб.\nЗарплата: {salary} руб.\nОстаток: {result} руб.', reply_markup=gorki_menu)

def get_collection_gorki(m):
    collection = m.text

    try:
        collection = int(collection)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Введены некорректные данные. Попробуйте снова')
        return

    current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM gorki_report WHERE date = ?", (current_date,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gorki_report(date, revenue, salary, result, collection) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (current_date, 0, 0, 0, collection))
    else:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE gorki_report SET collection = ? WHERE date = ?", (collection, current_date))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f'Инкас {current_date}:\nСумма инкаса: {collection} руб.', reply_markup=gorki_menu)

def cash_report_gorki(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(result) - SUM(collection) FROM gorki_report")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()

    if row is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нет данных для отчета")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Остаток нала: {row[0]} руб.", reply_markup=gorki_menu)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: The problem is solved. It was just the next step to return the bot to the function 'handle_palma_menu' or 'handle_gorki_menu'